# C pthread join/exit Threads (Exit wont work)

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

im trying to learn Threads, but i have a issue..
I'am trying to create multiple Threads as defined by ThreadCount and close them all after the work is done.

```
#define ThreadCount 5
```

just a short snippet of my main

```
pthread_t pro;
pthread_t con[ThreadCount];
pthread_attr_t attr;
pthread_attr_init(&attr);

pthread_create(&pro, &attr, producer, fifo);
for(unsigned int i = 0; i <ThreadCount;++i){
    pthread_create (&con[i], NULL, consumer, createhilfsStruct(i,fifo));
}
for(unsigned int i = 0; i <ThreadCount;++i){
    pthread_join (con[i], NULL);
}
pthread_join (pro, NULL);
printf("Done");
pthread_exit(NULL);
```

__

```
typedef struct{
    int threadName;
    queue* queue;
}hilfsStruct;

typedef struct {
    job* buf[QUEUESIZE];
    long head, tail;
    int full, empty, currentPages, done;
    pthread_mutex_t *mut;
    pthread_cond_t *notFull, *notEmpty;
} queue;

hilfsStruct* createhilfsStruct(int threadName, queue* q){
    hilfsStruct* h = (hilfsStruct*)malloc (sizeof (hilfsStruct));
    h->queue = q;
    h->threadName = threadName;
    return h;
}

queue *queueInit (void) {
    queue *q;

    q = (queue *)malloc (sizeof (queue));
    if (!q) return (NULL);

    q->empty = 1;
    q->full = 0;
    q->head = 0;
    q->tail = 0;
    q->currentPages = 0;
    q->done = 0;
    q->mut = (pthread_mutex_t *) malloc (sizeof (pthread_mutex_t));
    pthread_mutex_init (q->mut, NULL);
    q->notFull = (pthread_cond_t *) malloc (sizeof (pthread_cond_t));
    pthread_cond_init (q->notFull, NULL);
    q->notEmpty = (pthread_cond_t *) malloc (sizeof (pthread_cond_t));
    pthread_cond_init (q->notEmpty, NULL);

    return (q);
}
```

And in my consumer function i have a query to check if fifo->done is true and if its true i use exit(0); to kill the program ==> printf("Done") in the main cant get called [obviously]

If i swap the exit(0) for an pthread_exit(3); // i found this online but i cant figure out why 3

It doesn't exit the thread and the program is just idling and never closes / never reaches anything below the pthread_join

My first try was to use `pthread_t con, pro;` instead of `pthread_t con[..]` and just `pthread_join(con,NULL)` but that wasn't working either.

What am i doing wrong?

Ty guys, and have a nice day

Comment: What are your threads *actually* doing? Perhaps you can try to simplify them until they work, and then add a single little thing one step at a time until it stops working, and then locate the problematic code that way? Do you perhaps have a deadlock or data race? Have you tried using tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (more specifically its [Hellgrind and DRD tools](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html))?

Comment: hello @Someprogrammerdude ty for your answer! is everything i posted so far correct? this is my main.c https://pastebin.com/WCPbWnf6 || the producer is reading a file with links and the consumer is downloading the urls || askServer(const char* address, const char* page, const char* filename) || if you would like to download www.youtube.com/new you would pass it like askServer('www.youtube.com', '/new', file you would like to safe it to)

Comment: btw. the programm is finishing "correctly" if i kill it with exit(0) after all the jobs are done, but if i try to use pthread_exit(3)  the programm never stopps, so i guess it cant be a deadlock/data race right?

Comment: i dont know how to use valgrind but i compiled my main with gcc -Wall -Werror -g -pthread -std=c99 main.c socket.o -o test || then run valgrind || valgrind ./test | and the output was the same as before // no (valgrind) errors occured it still just idled after finishing the jobs

Comment: even if i try to swap pthread_exit(0) with printf("test") it doesnt output anything just exit(0) works so far but i just want to kill the thread not the whole program

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The snippets you have provided are not enough to diagnose the problem, though I suspect you have a locking issue somewhere.